Prove that a square rank $1$ matrix can have at most one eigenvalue different from $0$
I'm sure this can be proven in other ways, but I'm curious if the gap in the line of reasoning presented below can be filled so that the proof is valid.
Proof by contradiction.
Assume the opposite: There are two distinct eigenvalues of $A$, that is $\lambda_1, \lambda_2$ such that $\lambda_1 \neq \lambda_2$. Then, there exist eigenspaces $L_{\lambda_1}$ and $L_{\lambda_2}$. We know that all vectors from eigenspaces corresponding to different eigenvalues are linearly independent, that means that there exist eigenvectors $e_1 \in L_{\lambda_1}$ and $e_2 \in L_{\lambda_2}$ that are linearly independent. Here is the gap I want to fill, the contradiction I want to arrive at is "But since the rank of the matrix is 1, we can't have 2 linearly independent vectors". I know of a theorem that could perhaps help, it says that if we have a matrix $A=[a_{ij}], 1 \leq i, j \leq n$, then the rank of the matrix is equal to the dimension of the vector space which is spanned by the vectors $a_1, \dots a_n$ whose coordinates are rows of the matrix, respectively.

The rank is the dimension of the column space. Just reach the contradiction by showing the column space has at least two linearly independent vectors. Also, eventually you will need to use the “different from zero” assumption.

What you are supposed to prove is that $A$ has at most one non-zero eigenvalue with (algebraic) multiplicity so what you are doing won't get you there when you evidently assume for contradiction two non-zero eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\lambda_2$

One Approach you might take is the following.
Let $A \in K^{n\times n}$ for some field $K$.
Dimension theorem: rank($A$)=dim(image($A$)).
Now you can arrive at your contradiction, by assuming $v_1, v_2 \in K^n$ are eigenvectors to the eigenvalues $\lambda_1$ and $\lambda_2$.
Since the image of A is one dimensional, $Au=\mu Aw$ for all $u,w \in K^n$ and some $\mu \in K$.
With the eigenvalue Equation it follows, that $$\text{image}(A)=\text{span}(v_1)=\text{span}(v_2)$$ (since $Av_1=\lambda_1 v_1$ and thus $v_1 \in \text{image}(A)$ and the same holds for $v_2$ of course). By the result above it follows, that $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly dependent.

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. If you have eigenvalues $\lambda_1,\dots,\lambda_m$, then you can perform a base change (note that the rank does not change under base changes, since the transformation matrix is bijective), so that your matrix takes the form without restriction of generality:
$$ A = \left( \matrix{\lambda_1 \\ & \lambda_2 \\ & & \ddots \\ &&& \lambda_m \\&&&& B }\right).$$ Here $B$ is an $n-m$ square matrix. Let us assume, without restricting the generality, that $\lambda_1, \lambda_2 \neq 0$. Then both the first and the second row are linearly independent of the others. This is easy to see if you simply write out the row vectors. It follows that the rank of $A$ must be at least two, which is a contradiction.
